# Is there any code for 3D LOG filtering (or scale-normalized LoG filtering) for Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, filter

I want to use '**scale-normalized LoG filtering**' and so I try to use, `h = fspecial3('log',hsize,sigma);` but, when it is run an error occurs that 'No help found for fspecial3'. Whereas,`fspecial3` is found in this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial3.html#d120e64047). 
How to solve it?

Comment: The docs you link say "Introduced in R2018b" at the very bottom. Always a good thing to know that you can check that there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fspecial3`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/search.html?qdoc=fspecial3) doesn't seem to exist for R2017b.

[image]

By any chance, could you update Matlab to R2018b?

If not, there is the function [`imgaussfilt3`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/images/ref/imgaussfilt3.html) that can have similar results and that works in R2017b.

Comment: Could you describe how to obtain a LoG filter using `imgaussfilt3`? I don't see options for that in the documentation. You could do a difference of Gaussian approximation, but that is not the same, only an approximation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I don't have a complete knowledge of how to replace `fspecial3` within R2017b... I agree the Gaussian is not exactly the Laplacian of Gaussian, but it's the best alternative I found right now (but I might be wrong).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Can I ask about a paper in stackoverflow?

Comment: @eli: Yes, if it is about programming. There are many sister Stack Exchange web sites, I suggest you pick the right one if this is not about programming. For example https://dsp.stackexchange.com is the right place to ask more theoretical questions about image processing.

Comment: Hi, @eli. I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "ask about a paper"? You can discuss with matlab specialists here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave

Comment: @Bebs: Combination of paper and programming, because the needed concept for programming is in that paper.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I have a problem with my user name in Stack Exchange website, I asked a question and it creates a new profile with name of user40034. How to delete the new profile?

Comment: @eli: Meta SE has those type of answers, and you can ask those type of questions there. Your answer is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous